# Selecting first entry per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table will be structured like this

```
temp
ID | Date
---|-----------
1  | 2018-01-01
2  | 2018-01-01
3  | 2018-01-01
4  | 2018-01-02
5  | 2018-01-02
6  | 2018-01-03
```

And I will have an input from the user for start and end dates:

```
@StartDate DATE = '2018-01-01'
@EndDate DATE = '2018-01-03'
```

And I want my return structured like so:

```
ID | Date
---|-----------
1  | 2018-01-01
4  | 2018-01-02
6  | 2018-01-03
```

I've tried doing this:

```
select distinct temp.ID, joinTable.Date
from temp
inner join (
            select min(innerTemp.Date), innerTemp.ID
            from temp innerTemp
            where innerTemp.Date >= @StartDate
            and innerTemp.Date < @EndDate
            group by innerTemp.ID, innerTemp.Date
           ) as joinTable on joinTable.ID = temp.ID and joinTable.Date = temp.Date
where temp.Date >= @StartDate
and temp.Date < @EndDate
order by temp.Date desc
```

To try to join the table to itself with only one entry per day then choose from that but that isn't working. I am pretty stumped on this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems very complicated.  This returns the result set you want:

```
select min(id), date
from temp
where date >= @StartDate and date < @EndDate
group by date;
```

If you have other columns you want to keep (so `group by` is not appropriate), a simple method with good performance is:

```
select t.*
from temp t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id) from temp t2 where t2.date = t.date and t2.date >= @StartDate and t2.date < @EndDate);
```

Of course, you can also use `row_number()`, but with an index on `temp(date, id)` and `temp(id)`, the above should be pretty fast.

Comment: A working variant to return other columns would be: `select t.*
from temp t where t.id in (select min(id) from temp where date >= @StartDate and date < @EndDate group by date;)`, using the first solution as a subquery

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH cte AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY id asc) rn
    FROM 
        temp ) 
SELECT 
    id,
    date
FROM 
    rn = 1
```